# Robot running with gmapping can't achive given goal

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, every earnest folk

background : Anyone successfully let robot running with `gmapping` ? I have made my robot run with `amcl` and a given map , and it did something  very well ,such as going to the goal ,avoiding obstacle . In recent , I want to run my robot with `gmapping` , and I use old `base_local_planner` and `costmap` (including local & global) parameter .

gmapping params :

```
  <param name="particles" value="50" />

  <param name="maxUrange" value="200"/>
  <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="maxrang" value="220" />

  <param name="srr" value="0.2" />
  <param name="srt" value="0.4" />
  <param name="str" value="0.2" />
  <param name="stt" value="0.4" />
  <param name="map_update_interval" value="0.3" />
  <param name="transform_publish_period" value="0.5" />

  <param name="linearUpdate" value="1" />
  <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.5" />

  </node>
```

problem: robot can't achieve the goal given by rviz or rqt plugin written by myself . When I set a goal ,robot always performs `recovery behaviors` ,but the area around robot don't have any obstacle ,and the map showed in rviz is clean .

question 1: Are there some parameters about move_base need to be modified ?

question 2: In theory robot can running with gmapping , But in practically  ... ?

ps: ubuntu 12.04 & groovy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157396/robot-running-with-gmapping-can%27t-achive-given-goal/) by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-04-25**:
Are the goals in unknwon space?

**Comment by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on 2014-04-25**:
no, and I have set trace_unkown_spcae as true .

**Comment by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) on 2014-04-25**:
@dornhege  can you run your robot with gmapping ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1.my robot motor has some problem so that it can't walk forward along line .
2.After I called `clear_unknown_space` service , the robot's behavior looks well .

---

Originally posted by [zsbhaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13451/zsbhaha/) with karma: 63 on 2014-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0